# Need insert data click button by ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I need that by clicking on the button I can insert in the database by ajax in wordpress.Please, if you can help me. I do not know what is wrong

```js
// Script.js

function action() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.php',
        data: {------------------->What's going on there?               
        }, 
        success: function (data) {
            $("#result").html(response);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $("#result").html("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="" value="rating" id="button" onclick = "action();">

<div id="result"></div>

<!-- process.php -->
<?php
    global $wpdb;
               
    $wpdb->insert('rating', array( 
        'rating_postid'=>'5', 
        'rating_posttitle'=>'title'
        )
    ); 
?>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: when I click on the button I must register what is in process.php. the error is in script.js

Comment: in script.js the `??` are typos?

Comment: I do not know that goes in  data: {id:1},  ??
. By clicking on the button register process.php

Comment: In order to help, you need to provide more information about your problem.

Comment: I need to click on the button that is in index can register in the database what is in process.php. How would script.js be?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

HTML Code :

```
<input type="submit" name="" value="rating" id="button" onclick = "action();">

<div id="result"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function action() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.php',
        data: {
            id: 1
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#result").html(response);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $("#result").html("Error");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Your PHP file is okay..

Answer (score -1):

Html File

```
<input type="submit" name="" value="rating" id="but">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Javascript file

```
but=document.getElementById('but');
but.addEventListener('click', function (){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.php',
        data: {
            id: 1
        }, ??
        success: function (data) {
            $("#result").html(response);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $("#result").html("Error");
        }
    });
});
```

php file process.php

```
<?php
    $conn=mysqli_query('localhost','root','','DB');
    $query=' Insert Query '; 
    $fireResult=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    //json output
    json_encode($fireResult); 
?>
```